# Game sometimes crashes when closing or process stay in memory

Tags: c++, winapi

My problem is that sometimes, when closing the game, one of two may occur:

1. Process stays in memory and it have to be killed manually
2. Game crashes

I'm not sure if those two are related or completely independent issues. Both of those happen very rarely, but I have to eliminate these situations.

As for the crash, I made a dump and it says that the crash occurs in PeekMessage() function. The code looks like this:

```
bool running = true;

/// Reset timer
Timer.Reset();

MSG msg;
ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(msg));

/// message pump
while(running)
{
    int msg_count = 10;
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) && msg_count-->0)
    {
        ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
        ::DispatchMessage(&msg);

        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            running = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (ApplicationActive)
    {
        PrepareFrame();
        RenderFrame();
    }
    else
        Sleep(1);

    Sleep(1);
}
```

From what I see it, the message handling routine is handling at most 10 messages per loop iteration. Is it possible the crash is the result of overflowing message queue? And process staying in memory is the result of "not reaching" quit message because it's 
too far in the queue? If it helps, here's the call stack from dump:

```
ntdll.dll!_KiFastSystemCallRet@0()  
ntdll.dll!_ZwWaitForSingleObject@12()  + 0xc bytes  
ntdll.dll!_RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection@8()  + 0xc8 bytes  
ntdll.dll!_RtlEnterCriticalSection@4()  - 0x4b84 bytes  
ntdll.dll!_LdrLockLoaderLock@12()  + 0x6b bytes 
ntdll.dll!_LdrLoadDll@16()  + 0xd8 bytes    
kernel32.dll!_LoadLibraryExW@12()  + 0xf7 bytes 
user32.dll!___ClientLoadLibrary@4()  + 0x60 bytes   
ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()  + 0x2e bytes  
user32.dll!_NtUserPeekMessage@20()  + 0xc bytes 
user32.dll!__PeekMessage@24()  + 0x2d bytes 
user32.dll!_PeekMessageA@20()  + 0x572 bytes
```

> SchoolBus.exe!VCasualApp::Run()  Line 229 + 0x12 bytes  C++
>       SchoolBus.exe!wWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * **formal=0x00400000, HINSTANCE** * **formal=0x00400000, HINSTANCE** * **formal=0x00400000, HINSTANCE** * **formal=0x00400000)  Line 61 C++
>       SchoolBus.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 578 + 0x1c bytes    C
>       kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0x12 bytes
>
>       ntdll.dll!***RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes
>
>       ntdll.dll!*_RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but you should probably check the `running` flag before calling the `PrepareFrame` and `RenderFrame` functions.

Comment: When it hangs, pause it and see what's executing. Do you get a message when it crashes?

Comment: Just "Program is not responding", that's when I made a memory dump. As for the other situation: the game closes, DX is properly un-initialized, window destoryed (log file says so), but the process stays in the memory. It hapens rarely, today I had no luck trying to catch it.

Comment: Why don't you use standard message pump like in most DirectX/OpenGL games?

Comment: @Alex Farber what do you mean? Can you share a link with an example?

Comment: Well, something like this: http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=9-1-4 see `// Enter the infinite message loop`

Comment: On the other hand, you can prefer 100% Windows way of rendering, handling WM_PAINT message in `WndProc` + multimedia counter for animation, which invalidates the window with some interval.